# Laying out text in a TableRow

Tags: android, android-layout

I just started working on android and have a question about layouts. My app will display a scrolling list of stocks symbols, with data such as price, price change, volume, volume change.

This is my first android app so I'm still in the "how do you do all this" phase. Can you comment on how I've laid this out, or offer any suggestions on how to lay it out?

Right now I'm designing the TableRow format in the IDE. In the real app I'll be adding the TableRow's programmatically, I just need to figure out the layout. I've included an image of what I have now and my XML. The image contains a single TableRow showing one stock. Am I doing this ok, any horrible novice mistakes?

Thanks for any comments.

[image: example]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:background="#3fad86">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="GE"
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:textSize="50sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="80"
                android:background="#d52424">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:background="#ffe203">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="$54.32"
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:background="#76bfff"
                        android:layout_weight="50"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="($1.25)"
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:background="#f09ba0"
                        android:layout_weight="50"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="50">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="58492395"
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:background="#4bff0f"
                        android:layout_weight="50"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="(2052342)"
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:background="#00a6ff"
                        android:layout_weight="50"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:gravity="center" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want to use this layout for single resolution device or for more devices ?

Answer (score 1):

Your layout looks fine. You should be able to get the values in the textview programmatically